# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$[{"id":22,"title"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i use laravel 5.6
and i want to use product of selecet category

and i use of

```
    $product=Product::with('get_img')->where('product_status',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->limit(15)->get();

$category_products = Category::where('cat_ename', 'Electronic-Devices')->$product->get();
```

and i see this error that cant load product in category Electronic-Devices

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$[{"id":22,"title":"\u0645\u0627\u06af \u0645\u0627\u06af\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u062f\u0644 mg0011","code":"magh","title_url":"\u0645\u0627\u06af-\u0645\u0627\u06af\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646-\u0645\u062f\u0644-mg0011","code_url":"magh","price":23000,"discounts":2000,"view":0,"text":"<p>\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0627\u06af, \u0628\u0635\u0648\u0631\u062a \u0627\u062e\u062a\u0635\u0627\u0635\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u0637\u0631\u062d \u06a9\u0631\u06cc\u0633\u0645\u0633 \u0637\u0631\u0627\u062d\u06cc \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a.<\/p>","product_status":1,"bon":2,"show_product":1,"product_number":2,"order_product":0,"keywords":",\u06cc\u0628\u06cc","description":"\u0628\u06cc\u0633\u0628\u0633\u06cc\u0628\u0633\u0628\u06cc","special":0,"created_at":"2018-11-08 21:23:03","updated_at":"2018-11-08 21:23:03","get_img":{"id":49,"product_id":22,"url":"ab2576657af399fcf67069526e646ff2.jpg"}},{"id":20,"title":"\u0647\u0646\u062f\u0632\u0641\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0644\u0648\u062a\u0648\u062b \u0631\u06cc\u0645\u06a9\u0633 \u0645\u062f\u0644 RB-T10","code":"Remax RB-T10 Bluetooth Handsfree","title_url":"\u0647\u0646\u062f\u0632\u0641\u0631\u06cc-\u0628\u0644\u0648\u062a\u0648\u062b-\u0631\u06cc\u0645\u06a9\u0633-\u0645\u062f\u0644-RBT10","code_url":"Remax-RBT10-Bluetooth-Handsfree","price":75000,"discounts":59000,"view":1,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-02-12 03:44:56","updated_at":"2018-02-13 11:01:14","get_img":{"id":46,"product_id":20,"url":"b1bef936250ceef572767550c0c57ea0.jpg"}},{"id":19,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644 \u062c\u064a \u0645\u062f\u0644 K10 \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a \u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a 16 \u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code":"LG K10 Dual SIM 16GB Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0627\u0644-\u062c\u064a-\u0645\u062f\u0644-K10-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a-\u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a-16-\u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code_url":"LG-K10-Dual-SIM-16GB-Mobile-Phone","price":587000,"discounts":null,"view":50,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":1,"created_at":"2018-02-07 20:48:02","updated_at":"2018-06-27 07:55:20","get_img":{"id":41,"product_id":19,"url":"1b467283a7241eb34121ff02f42124ab.jpg"}},{"id":18,"title":"\u0644\u067e \u062a\u0627\u067e 13 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686\u06cc \u0627\u067e\u0644 \u0645\u062f\u0644 MacBook Air MQD32 2017","code":"Apple MacBook Air MQD32 2017 - 13 inch Laptop","title_url":"\u0644\u067e-\u062a\u0627\u067e-13-\u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686\u06cc-\u0627\u067e\u0644-\u0645\u062f\u0644-MacBook-Air-MQD32-2017","code_url":"Apple-MacBook-Air-MQD32-2017-13-inch-Laptop","price":4656000,"discounts":100000,"view":2,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-01-14 21:32:24","updated_at":"2018-04-30 08:17:59","get_img":{"id":23,"product_id":18,"url":"96910b91ae8eb30918953426051cae14.jpg"}},{"id":17,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0633\u0648\u0646\u064a \u0645\u062f\u0644 Xperia XA Ultra \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a \u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a 16 \u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code":"Sony Xperia XA Ultra Dual SIM 16GB Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0633\u0648\u0646\u064a-\u0645\u062f\u0644-Xperia-XA-Ultra-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645-\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a-\u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a-16-\u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code_url":"Sony-Xperia-XA-Ultra-Dual-SIM-16GB-Mobile-Phone","price":1050000,"discounts":41000,"view":1,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-01-09 07:14:54","updated_at":"2018-02-08 14:12:24","get_img":{"id":21,"product_id":17,"url":"a2e060dff0afc61e14fae3c5a653880d.jpg"}},{"id":16,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0633\u0648\u0646\u064a \u0645\u062f\u0644 Xperia C5 Ultra \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code":"Sony Xperia C5 Ultra Dual SIM Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0633\u0648\u0646\u064a-\u0645\u062f\u0644-Xperia-C5-Ultra-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code_url":"Sony-Xperia-C5-Ultra-Dual-SIM-Mobile-Phone","price":1000000,"discounts":65000,"view":4,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-01-07 22:18:05","updated_at":"2018-02-08 14:17:08","get_img":{"id":19,"product_id":16,"url":"c0da3344792c8a8cba0c8a91c16f4ea9.jpg"}},{"id":15,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0647\u0648\u0622\u0648\u064a \u0645\u062f\u0644 Honor 8 \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code":"Huawei Honor 8 Dual SIM Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0647\u0648\u0622\u0648\u064a-\u0645\u062f\u0644-Honor-8-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645-\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code_url":"Huawei-Honor-8-Dual-SIM-Mobile-Phone","price":1492000,"discounts":null,"view":0,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-01-07 22:12:51","updated_at":"2018-01-07 22:12:51","get_img":{"id":15,"product_id":15,"url":"e0d803d3514aba12b5f816a7772b1f7b.jpg"}},{"id":14,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0645\u062f\u0644 Galaxy A5 2017 \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code":"Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017) Dual SIM Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af-\u0645\u062f\u0644-Galaxy-A5-2017-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code_url":"Samsung-Galaxy-A5-(2017)-Dual-SIM-Mobile-Phone","price":1345000,"discounts":null,"view":4,"text":"<p>\u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0631\u062f\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc &laquo;\u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af&raquo; \u0647\u0631\u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0628\u0627 \u0646\u0627\u0645&zwnj; \u0648 \u067e\u0633\u0648\u0646\u062f\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u0639\u0631\u0641\u06cc \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u0634\u0648\u0646\u062f \u0648 \u0641\u0642\u0637 \u0628\u0627 \u0686\u0646\u062f \u062a\u063a\u06cc\u06cc\u0631 \u06a9\u0648\u0686\u06a9 \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u062e\u062a\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u062c\u0647\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06af\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u062f. \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u0633\u0644 \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A \u0631\u0648\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u0642\u0635\u062f \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u0632\u0648\u062f\u06cc \u0622\u0646&zwnj;\u0647\u0627 \u0631\u0627 \u0631\u0648\u0627\u0646\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u0628\u0627\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062c\u0647\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af &laquo;\u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A5 2017 \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u06cc\u0645&zwnj;\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a&raquo; (Galaxy A5 2017 Dual SIM) \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0631\u06cc\u060c \u06cc\u06a9 \u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0631\u062f\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u0628\u0627\u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u0647&zwnj; \u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u0622\u06cc\u062f. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f \u0634\u0628\u0627\u0647\u062a \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0633\u0644 \u0642\u0628\u0644\u06cc \u062e\u0648\u062f \u0627\u0632 \u0648\u06cc\u0698\u06af\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u0646\u0646\u062f \u0645\u0642\u0627\u0648\u0645\u062a \u062f\u0631 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u0628\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u062f\u0648\u063a\u0628\u0627\u0631 \u0648 \u0622\u0628 \u062a\u0627 \u0639\u0645\u0642 1.5 \u0645\u062a\u0631 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f\u062a 30 \u062f\u0642\u06cc\u0642\u0647 \u0628\u0647\u0631\u0647 \u0628\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u0622\u0646 \u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u0647\u0645\u062a\u0627\u06cc 2016 \u062e\u0648\u062f \u0645\u062a\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0632 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u0633\u062e\u062a&zwnj;\u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0646\u062c\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0633\u06cc\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0645\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u0641\u06cc\u062f \u0628\u0627\u0634\u062f\u060c \u0628\u062f\u0646\u0647&zwnj;\u0627\u06cc \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627 \u0648 \u0686\u0634\u0645&zwnj;\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0632\u060c \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a\u0634 \u0686\u0634\u0645&zwnj;\u0647\u0627 \u0631\u0627 \u062e\u06cc\u0631\u0647 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f\u060c \u062d\u0633\u06af\u0631 \u0627\u062b\u0631\u0627\u0646\u06af\u0634\u062a \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0645\u0646\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u06cc\u0634\u062a\u0631 \u0648 \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0641\u0648\u0642&zwnj;\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u062b\u0628\u062a \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f\u060c \u0627\u0632 \u0645\u0634\u062e\u0635\u0627\u062a \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0646\u062f. \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0631 \u062f\u0631 \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A5 2017\u060c \u062a\u0631\u0627\u0634\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc 64\u0628\u06cc\u062a\u06cc \u0627\u06af\u0632\u06cc\u0646\u0648\u0633 7880 \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 8 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0646\u062f\u0647&zwnj; \u0628\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u06a9\u0648\u0631\u062a\u06a9\u0633 A53 \u0628\u0627 \u0642\u062f\u0631\u062a \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0634 1.9 \u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0647\u0631\u062a\u0632 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f\u061b 3 \u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u0631\u0645 \u062f\u0631 \u06a9\u0646\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062c\u0645\u0648\u0639\u0647 \u0633\u062e\u062a&zwnj;\u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f \u062a\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u0647\u0631\u0686\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u062a\u0631\u0634\u062f\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u06a9\u0645\u06a9 \u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A5 2017 \u0627\u0632 \u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644\u06cc 32\u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a\u06cc \u0628\u0647\u0631\u0647 \u0628\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a \u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u062c\u0627\u0646\u0628\u06cc \u062a\u0627 256 \u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u0631\u0627 \u067e\u0634\u062a\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u0637\u0628\u0642 \u0631\u0648\u0627\u0644 \u062a\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0647\u0648\u0634\u0645\u0646\u062f\u060c \u0627\u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0641\u0646\u0627\u0648\u0631\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0645\u062b\u0644 \u0628\u0644\u0648\u062a\u0648\u062b\u060c Wi-Fi\u0648 NFC \u0647\u0645 \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f \u06a9\u0647 \u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 A5 2017 \u0628\u0647 \u0627\u0631\u0645\u063a\u0627\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0627\u0647\u062f \u0622\u0648\u0631\u062f. \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u067e\u0646\u0644 OLED \u0648 \u0641\u0646\u0627\u0648\u0631\u06cc Super AMOLED \u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u0627\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc 5.2 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686 \u0648 \u0631\u0632\u0648\u0644\u0648\u0634\u0646 FullHD&nbsp; \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u0631\u0633\u062f. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0627 \u0627\u0634\u0628\u0627\u0639 \u0631\u0646\u06af \u0686\u0634\u0645&zwnj;\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0632 \u0648 \u0628\u0627 \u062a\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u0645 \u0645\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0628 424 \u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644 \u0628\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686 \u0628\u0647 \u062a\u0635\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0628\u06a9\u0634\u062f. \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u062a \u0627\u0632 \u0622\u0646 \u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0632 \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0646\u0633\u062e\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u06af\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u0644\u0627\u06af\u0644\u0633 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631 \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0627\u0641\u062a \u062a\u0627 5 \u0644\u0645\u0633 \u0647\u0645&zwnj;\u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0646 \u0648 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645&zwnj;\u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646 \u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0628 \u062e\u0648\u0627\u0647\u062f \u0628\u0648\u062f. \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u067e\u0627\u0633\u062e \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u06cc\u0627\u0632 \u0639\u0644\u0627\u0642\u0647&zwnj;\u0645\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0647 \u0639\u06a9\u0627\u0633\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644\u060c \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u0646\u0633\u0648\u0631 16\u0645\u06af\u0627\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644\u06cc \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0631 A5 2017 \u0628\u0647 \u062e\u062f\u0645\u062a \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0646 \u0627\u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u0641\u0631\u0627\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u06cc\u06a9 \u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u0631\u0633\u062f. \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0628\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u0635\u0644\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u0641\u0644\u0634\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u0648\u0639 LED \u0645\u062c\u0647\u0632 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u060c \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u0646\u0648\u0631 \u06a9\u0645 \u0647\u0645 \u0639\u0645\u0644\u06a9\u0631\u062f \u062e\u0648\u0628\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u062e\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634 \u0628\u06af\u0630\u0627\u0631\u062f. \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0628\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0644\u0641\u06cc \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc&nbsp; A5 \u0647\u0645 \u0633\u0646\u0633\u0648\u0631\u06cc 16\u0645\u06af\u0627\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0686\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u0627\u0641\u0631\u0627\u06af\u0645 \u0628\u0627\u0632&zwnj;\u062a\u0631 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f \u06a9\u0647 \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u0646\u0648\u0631 \u0628\u06cc\u0634\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u062c\u0630\u0628 \u0648 \u062f\u0631\u0646\u062a\u06cc\u062c\u0647 \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0647\u0645 \u062b\u0628\u062a \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A5 \u0627\u0632 \u062a\u0631\u06a9\u06cc\u0628 \u0641\u0644\u0632 \u0648 \u0634\u06cc\u0634\u0647 \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u06cc\u0645&zwnj;\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a \u062f\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u06cc\u0632 \u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 \u067e\u0634\u062a\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0631 \u0645\u0634\u062e\u0635\u0627\u062a \u0638\u0627\u0647\u0631\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0647 \u0636\u062e\u0627\u0645\u062a 7.9 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06cc&zwnj;\u0645\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u060c \u0637\u0648\u0644 146.1 \u0648 \u0639\u0631\u0636 71.4 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06cc&zwnj;\u0645\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0645\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0628\u0634 \u0628\u0627 \u062f\u0631\u0646\u0638\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631 5.2\u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686\u06cc&zwnj; \u0622\u0646 \u0627\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u06a9\u0631\u062f. \u062f\u0631 \u0646\u0633\u0644 \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u06af\u0644\u06a9\u0633\u06cc A5 \u0627\u0646\u062f\u0631\u0648\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0648 \u0627\u06cc\u0641\u0627\u06cc \u0646\u0642\u0634 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u06a9\u0646\u062f \u0648 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0628\u0627\u062a\u0631\u06cc 3000 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06cc&zwnj;\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0639\u062a\u06cc \u0648\u0638\u06cc\u0641\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u062a\u0623\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u0646\u0631\u0698\u06cc \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0631 \u0639\u0647\u062f\u0647 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f. \u0627\u06af\u0631 \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0647\u0633\u062a\u06cc\u062f\u060c \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0634\u0631\u06a9\u062a \u0628\u0627 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 A5 2017 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646&zwnj;\u0631\u062f\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u0642\u062f\u0631\u062a\u0645\u0646\u062f \u0628\u062e\u0634 \u0639\u0645\u062f\u0647&zwnj;\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u06cc\u0627\u0632\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u0631\u0627 \u067e\u0627\u0633\u062e&zwnj;\u06af\u0648 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u062f.<\/p>","product_status":1,"bon":2,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2018-01-07 22:00:46","updated_at":"2018-04-01 08:09:28","get_img":{"id":12,"product_id":14,"url":"1b1849b3c938ffe6d1962a6f5809997a.jpg"}},{"id":12,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u067e\u0644 \u0645\u062f\u0644 iPhone 7 Plus \u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a 32 \u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code":"Apple iPhone 7 Plus 32GB Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0627\u067e\u0644-\u0645\u062f\u0644-iPhone-7-Plus-\u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a-32-\u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code_url":"Apple-iPhone-7-Plus-32GB-Mobile-Phone","price":3099000,"discounts":100000,"view":23,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2017-10-21 05:54:51","updated_at":"2018-07-25 16:08:34","get_img":{"id":9,"product_id":12,"url":"82011bd42ee3d9d3ef0d74e02a5c72c6.jpg"}},{"id":11,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u067e\u0644 \u0645\u062f\u0644 iPhone 6s \u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a 64 \u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code":"Apple iPhone 6s 64GB Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0644-\u0627\u067e\u0644-\u0645\u062f\u0644-iPhone-6s-\u0638\u0631\u0641\u064a\u062a-64-\u06af\u064a\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u064a\u062a","code_url":"Apple-iPhone-6s-64GB-Mobile-Phone","price":2449000,"discounts":11000,"view":15,"text":null,"product_status":1,"bon":null,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":0,"created_at":"2017-10-21 04:38:07","updated_at":"2018-07-04 14:18:06","get_img":{"id":8,"product_id":11,"url":"c17ab5a5d24eab5fe8f5b6df40f8b71b.jpg"}},{"id":10,"title":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0645\u062f\u0644 Galaxy J7 Prime SM-G610FD \u062f\u0648 \u0633\u064a\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code":"Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime SM-G610FD Dual SIM Mobile Phone","title_url":"\u06af\u0648\u0634\u064a-\u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644-\u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af-\u0645\u062f\u0644-Galaxy-J7-Prime-SMG610FD-\u062f\u0648-\u0633\u064a\u0645-\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062a","code_url":"Samsung-Galaxy-J7-Prime-SMG610FD-Dual-SIM-Mobile-Phone","price":949000,"discounts":31000,"view":129,"text":"<p>\u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 &laquo;\u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af&raquo; \u0645\u062f\u0644 &laquo;Galaxy J7 Prime&raquo; \u06cc\u06a9\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u0647\u06a9\u0634\u0627\u0646\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0634\u0631\u06a9\u062a \u06a9\u0631\u0647&zwnj;\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u062a\u0627\u0632\u06af\u06cc \u067e\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062c\u0647\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u06af\u0630\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u062a\u0631\u0627\u0634\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u0627\u06af\u0632\u06cc\u0646\u0648\u0633 7870\u060c 3 \u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u0631\u0645\u060c 16 \u06af\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644\u06cc \u0648 \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0646\u062f\u0647&zwnj;\u06cc \u06af\u0631\u0627\u0641\u06cc\u06a9\u06cc Mali-T830MP2 \u0633\u062e\u062a&zwnj;\u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u0631 \u0642\u062f\u0631\u062a\u0645\u0646\u062f J7 Prime \u0631\u0627 \u062a\u0634\u06a9\u06cc\u0644 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062f\u0647\u0646\u062f.&nbsp;\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0647&zwnj;\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634 5.5 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686\u06cc \u0622\u0646 \u06a9\u0647 \u062a\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u0645\u06cc \u0628\u0631\u0627\u0628\u0631 401 \u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644 \u0628\u0631 \u0647\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0686 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f\u060c \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u0648\u0639 LCD \u0627\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u0641\u0646\u0627\u0648\u0631\u06cc&nbsp;TFT \u062f\u0631 \u0622\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a.<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><!--more-->\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0635\u0641\u062d\u0647&zwnj;\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634 \u06a9\u0647 \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634 16 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06cc\u0648\u0646 \u0631\u0646\u06af \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f\u060c \u0627\u0632 \u0631\u0632\u0648\u0644\u0648\u0634\u0646 1920&times;1080 \u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644 \u0628\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u0634\u0631\u06a9\u062a \u0633\u0627\u0645\u0633\u0648\u0646\u06af \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u062a \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0635\u0641\u062d\u0647&zwnj;\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u060c \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638 \u06af\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u0644\u0627\u06af\u0644\u0633 \u0646\u0648\u0639 4&nbsp;\u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u062f\u0644\u06cc\u0644 \u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u06cc\u0634 \u0645\u0642\u0627\u0648\u0645\u062a \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u0628\u0631 \u062e\u0637 \u0648 \u062e\u0634 \u0648 \u0628\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0631\u062f \u0628\u0627 \u0633\u0637\u0648\u062d \u0633\u062e\u062a \u0627\u0632 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0647&zwnj;\u062e\u0648\u0628\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u062a \u06a9\u0646\u062f. \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0628\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u0628\u0647&nbsp; \u0633\u0646\u0633\u0648\u0631\u06cc 13 \u0645\u06af\u0627\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644\u06cc \u0645\u062c\u0647\u0632 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0646 \u0627\u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u0646\u0646\u062f \u0641\u0648\u06a9\u0648\u0633 \u0628\u0627 \u0627\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u06cc \u0633\u0648\u0698\u0647 (Touch Focus)\u060c \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u062a\u0634\u062e\u06cc\u0635 \u0686\u0647\u0631\u0647 (Face Detection)\u060c \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u06a9\u0627\u0633\u06cc \u067e\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0645\u0627 \u0648 \u0639\u06a9\u0627\u0633\u06cc HDR \u0627\u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646 \u062b\u0628\u062a \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0648\u06cc\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u0648\u0636\u0648\u062d \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u062e\u062a\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u062f\u0631 \u06a9\u0646\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0646\u0633\u0648\u0631 \u0642\u062f\u0631\u062a\u0645\u0646\u062f\u060c \u0633\u0646\u0633\u0648\u0631\u06cc 8 \u0645\u06af\u0627\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0644\u06cc \u062f\u0631 \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0628\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0644\u0641\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u062c\u0627\u06cc \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0645\u0642\u0627\u06cc\u0633\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u0628\u0633\u06cc\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0645\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0645\u0634\u0627\u0628\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u0627\u0631<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>\u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u06cc\u06a9\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0648\u06cc\u0698\u06af\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062c\u06cc 7 \u067e\u0631\u0627\u06cc\u0645 \u067e\u0634\u062a\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0646\u062a \u067e\u0631 \u0633\u0631\u0639\u062a 4G \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0633\u0631\u0639\u062a \u062f\u0627\u0646\u0644\u0648\u062f\u06cc \u0645\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0644 150 \u0645\u06af\u0627\u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u0631 \u062b\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0647 \u0631\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u062e\u062a\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u0645\u06cc&zwnj;\u062f\u0647\u062f. \u062f\u0631 \u06a9\u0646\u0627\u0631 \u0645\u062c\u0647\u0632&zwnj;\u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646 \u0628\u0647 \u0634\u0628\u06a9\u0647 4G\u060c \u067e\u0634\u062a\u06cc\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0641\u0646\u0627\u0648\u0631\u06cc&zwnj;\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0631\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0637\u06cc EDGE &nbsp;,GPRS, Wi-Fi&nbsp;\u0648 \u0628\u0644\u0648\u062a\u0648\u062b \u0646\u0633\u062e\u0647 4.1 \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0648\u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u06cc\u0634\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u06af\u0648\u0634\u06cc \u0662a \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06af\u0631 \u062f\u0631 \u0622\u0646 \u0628\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a.&nbsp;<\/p>","product_status":1,"bon":4,"show_product":1,"product_number":null,"order_product":0,"keywords":null,"description":null,"special":1,"created_at":"2017-10-07 22:17:11","updated_at":"2018-07-27 12:53:36","get_img":{"id":1,"product_id":10,"url":"2601744190892df297417f225fa4cad2.jpg"}}]
```

please help me

my website

http://bonabe.ir/category/Electronic-Devices

Comment: Have you defined a relationship between products and categories? If so you should be able to use a join or filter by the related property to get the result you need.

Comment: @Don'tPanic which relationship between products and categories? i add website address...thank you

Comment: Relationships like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: What is `->$product->get();` supposed to do?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes...this should be get all product in category Electronic-Devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$` from

```
->$product
```

You need to create a relationship first:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $category_products = Category::where('cat_ename', 'Electronic-Devices')
        ->first()
        ->products
        ->all();

        return view('index', [
            'category_products' => $category_products
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i removed and see this error . Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$product

Comment: $category_products = Category::where('cat_ename', 'Electronic-Devices')->product;

Comment: Create a relationship in your `Category` model for your product. `public function product()...`

Comment: public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class,'code_url','id')->orderBy('id','ASC');
    }

Comment: but error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$product –

Comment: @stackower use `->first()` after your `where`

Comment: Undefined variable: category_products (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/digikala/resources/views/site/index.blade.php)

Comment: this work but i have a  one issue...when using $category_products error undefined

Comment: @stackower updated answer with more detail. see if that helps

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /Users/tohidda/Desktop/digikala/edited file/laravel/1/digikala/app/Http/Controllers/SiteController.php on line 56 and at least 1 expected

Comment: change `->get` to `->all()` unless you know exactly what you want from the products, then you can pass arguments into the get method: `->get('id', 'name')`